# Replace Ctr+H copy row and change it 

Tags: python, regex

I need some help.

I have many rows in my text file with this :

```
invoke glVertex3f,-0.352848,0.081168,-0.123057
```

I want to copy each row before him and change glVertex3f with glColor3f.
The result will be like this:

```
invoke glColor3f,-0.352848,0.081168,-0.123057
invoke glVertex3f,-0.352848,0.081168,-0.123057
```

I want to make this with python **or** ctr+h (replace dialog - like geany editor with regex pattern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Python 2.7/3.1+ you can do this:

```
with open('input.txt') as input, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        output.write(line.replace('glVertex3f', 'glColor3f'))
        output.write(line)
```

In earlier versions would nest the `with` statements.